# Does the St Petersburg Paradox happen for Finite Length Games?

Tags: probability

I am learning about the St Petersburg Paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox - here is my attempt to summarize it:

- A fair coin is tossed at each stage.
- The initial stake begins at 2 dollars and is doubled every time heads appears.
- The first time tails appears, the game ends and the player wins whatever is the current stake

As we can see, this game will have an expected reward of infinite dollars:

$$E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i \cdot p_i$$

$$E  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot 2^n = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 4 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 8 + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 16 + ...  = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1  =  \infty$$

The paradox is that even though the game has an infinite reward, in real life simulations, the game usually ends up with a finite reward. Although seemingly counterintuitive, this does seem logical. Even more, we can write computer simulations to see that large number of games will have finite rewards.

I now have the following question: **Does this paradox also happen if the game has finite length?** (i.e. played to a maximum of 10 turns or the appearance of the first tails). **Will the expected reward match the "true" reward?**

For example, in a 10 turn game, here is the formula we would use for the expectation:

$$E_{10}(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i \cdot p_i$$
$$E_{10}  = \sum_{n=1}^{10} \frac{1}{2^n} \cdot 2^n = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 4 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot 8 + \frac{1}{16} \cdot 16 + ... + \frac{1}{2^{10}} \cdot 2^{10} = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 = 10$$

I then wrote an R function to simulate multiple such games:

```
simulate_games <- function(n = 10000, max_turns = 10) {

  results <- data.frame(game_number = integer(), number_of_turns = integer(), final_reward = numeric())
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    turns <- 0
    reward <- 0
    
    while (turns < max_turns && runif(1) > 0.5) {
      turns <- turns + 1
      reward <- 2^(turns )
    }
    
    results <- rbind(results, data.frame(game_number = i, number_of_turns = turns, final_reward = reward))
  }
  
  return(results)
}

results <- simulate_games()
```

When analyzing the results, I noticed the following:

```
> mean(results$number_of_turns)
[1] 1.0001

> mean(results$final_reward)
[1] 5.5692
```

Thus, it would appear that even though the expected reward in a 10 turn St Petersburg Paradox game is 10 dollars ... we only get an average reward of 5.5 dollars. **Thus, it seems like the paradox still happens even in a finite St Petersburg paradox?**

**In general, is there some mathematical formula which can be used to determine the average reward to be encountered in a simulated St Petersburg Paradox without actually performing the simulations?**